# Desarrollo de clases Java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer el ejercicio que nos han mandado en clase, os pongo el enunciado.

En la clase Corredor:

Atributos(privados)

nombre: nombre del socio (cadena)

nif: nif del socio (cadena)

edad: edad del corredor (valor numérico entero)

numDorsal: número de corredor (valor numérico entero). Atributo estático.

dorsalActivo: que indica si el dorsal esta activo (variable booleana)

numMinutos: número de minutos que ha tardado el corredor en realizar la maratón. Al crear el cada objeto de este tipo se inicializará a 0. A lo largo del programa se tendrá en cuenta que el tiempo no puede ser menor que 0 ni la maratón durará más de 12 horas.

Métodos (a los que se tenga acceso desde un mismo paquete)

·         Constructor de objetos Corredor sin parámetros.

·         Constructor de objetos Constructor con tres argumentos que de valor a los primeros atributos.

·         Constructor de objetos Corredor con dos argumentos, nif y edad, que siempre asigne por nombre “Invitado”.

·         Constructor Copia de objeto Corredor.

Mi pregunta: ¿Tengo que hacer cuatro constructores 3 de corredor y otro de constructor? ¿Cómo consigo hacer las cuatro opciones, sabiendo que no puedo hacer varios constructores con paramentros? Al menos el programa me da fallo.

Os dejo mi código:

```
public class Corredor {
    private String nombre;
    private String nif;
    private int edad;
    private static int numDorsal;
    private boolean dorsalActivo;
    private int numMinutos;

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre=nombre;
    }
    public String getNif(){
        return nif;
    }
    public void setNif(String nif){
        this.nif=nif;
    }
    public int getEdad(){
        return edad;
    }
    public void setEdad(int edad){
        this.edad=edad;
    }
    public int getNumdorsal(){
        return numDorsal;
    }
    public void setNumdorsal(int numDorsal){
        this.numDorsal=numDorsal;
    }
    public boolean getDorsalActivo(){
        return dorsalActivo;
    }
    public void setDorsalActivo(boolean dorsalActivo){
        this.dorsalActivo=dorsalActivo;
    }
    public int getNumMinutos(){
        return numMinutos;
    }
    public void setNumMinutos(int numMinutos){
        this.numMinutos=numMinutos;
    }
    //sin argumentos
    public Corredor(){

    }
    //con argumentos
    Corredor(String nombre, String nif, int edad, int numDorsal, boolean dorsalActivo, int numMinutos){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.nif=nif;
        this.edad=edad;
        this.numDorsal=numDorsal;
        this.dorsalActivo=dorsalActivo;
        this.numMinutos=numMinutos;
    }

    //con los tres primeros arguemntos y aqui es donde me da fallo dado que la clase corredor está declarada
    public Corredor(){
        nombre="Pepe";
        nif="740325679E";
        edad=57;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sí que puedes crear distintos constructores según los parámetros que se necesiten. Te recomiendo leer sobre polimorfismo en java

Comment: Hola, coloca el error que te da la aplicación

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo tu error esta en que quieres tener dos constructores vacíos lo cual no es posible, te recomiendo que le des una vista al tema de [sobrecarga de constructores](http://profesores.fi-b.unam.mx/carlos/java/java_basico4_6.html), ya que es el tema que necesitas para solucionar el error.
Recuerda que si se puede tener varios constructores siempre y cuando los parámetros sean diferentes.

Por ejemplo tu primer constructor esta bien.

```
   public Corredor() {

}
```

En el caso del segundo también está bien dado que los parámetros son diferentes, lo que cumple con los principios de la sobrecarga de constructores.

Pero deacuerdo a lo solicitado quedaria algo asi.

```
   public corredor(String nombre, String nif, int edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.nif = nif;
        this.edad = edad;
    }
```

Pero el error esta en el tercer constructor que intentas realizar, el cual no puede ser definido dado que ya tienes un constructor vació que es es el primero.

Y en tu enunciado dice `

> Constructor de objetos Corredor con dos argumentos, nif y edad, que
>   siempre asigne por nombre “Invitado”.

Por lo que tiene que quedar algo asi.

```
 public Corredor(String nif, int edad) {
        this.nombre = "Invitado";
        this.nif = nif;
        this.edad = edad;
    }
```

Y si con el ultimo constructor y con en base a la [documentación](https://www.abrirllave.com/java/sobrecarga-de-metodos-y-constructores.php) que te sugiero puedes realizarlo sin ningún problema.

Saludos